# Swiftmailer DKIM fails only with multipart email

Tags: php, swiftmailer, dkim

I'm attempting to get DKIM working with Swiftmailer from PHP.  It works and the dkim passes when only setting the body once (HTML or Text), however when adding both parts I get a "body hash did not verify" dkim fail.

Does anyone know the correct way to sign an email with both HTML and text parts using Swiftmailer?

```
// Create the signer    
$privateKey = file_get_contents($dkimPrivateKeyLocation);
$domainName = 'from.here';
$selector = 'default';
$signer = new Swift_Signers_DKIMSigner($privateKey, $domainName, $selector);
$signer->ignoreHeader('Return-Path');

// Create the message
$message = Swift_SignedMessage::newInstance();                  

// Attach the signer
$message->attachSigner($signer);

// Message setup
$message->setFrom('email@from.here');
$message->setTo('email@to.here');
```

HTML only **passes**

```
$message->setSubject('Dkim Html Only Test');
$message->setBody('<p>Hello World</p>', 'text/html','UTF-8');
```

TEXT only **passes**

```
$message->setSubject('Dkim Text Only Test');
$message->setBody('Hello World', 'text/plain','UTF-8');
```

HTML and Text **fails**

```
$message->setSubject('Dkim Html and Text Test');
$message->setBody('<p>Hello World</p>', 'text/html','UTF-8'); 
$message->addPart('Hello World', 'text/plain','UTF-8');
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the SwiftMailer documentation is a little sparse so I'm not sure what to try next.  I have tried both simple and relaxed types for the body canon with no success.

Comment: Maybe I need to sign the two body types separately somehow?

Comment: I too want to know this.  I can't find any documentation on sending DKIM messages with swiftmail.  Did you get anywhere with this in the end?